# Light fixtures flicker after replacement

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I have replaced the two lights in my kitchen with updated fixtures.  These lights are controlled by the same switch.  The first light went in with no problems.  The second one is a little bit more complicated.  There are supposed to be the three wires distinguishable by color.  Only the green, grounding wire is obvious.  The other two are not. I think that I have them correctly connected but the lights on both fixtures flicker when I turn the switch on.  Is it possible that I have wired them incorrectly or is this a separate issue?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: If both lights flicker it sounds more like a wire is not securely attached - probably on the first fixture closest to your switch (this might be hard to tell).  But more often flickering is a loose connection not wired wrong.

Comment: The lights replaced were 2, three-light multi directional ceiling lights. I replaced one with an updated version of the three light and the one above my sink with a pendant light.  The pendant is a Westinghouse 70284 and the other is an IKEA three light multi directional. The other wires are both white/silver. The instructions state that one has a slight brownish color to it which is supposed to go the black. (As I said though, these other two are virtually identical and I was guessing that I had the brownish one identified).

Comment: Interesting!  Well I installed that light closest to the switch first and it worked fine.  It was when I installed the second light that the flickering began

Comment: If you have a volt meter measure the voltage from the copper wire to the white / silver wires the wire that shows voltage should be the one going to the black.

Answer (score 1):

The power feed to a single phase fixture can be connected either way. The fixture doesn't care or at least I have never seen one that does.

Are these fluorescent fixtures? The flickering could mean you didn't seat the lamps well enough into their sockets. The pins should go straight in and then twist the lamp ¼ turn to seat them firmly.

They should flicker slightly when they are brand new and first turned on but the tubes will "burn-in" in just a few hours. Leave the lights on for a couple hours to allow them to burn in and they should stop flickering or strobing.

Otherwise they flicker slightly as the are turned on anyway depending on the type of starter in the fixture. This should only be a split second though and they should come up to full brightness.

Happy Friday!